# Last hour doesn't appear on FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a problem with my FullCalendar, the last our doesn't appear and instead, a strange div without anything appears.

The following images will explain better
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qioc.jpg) link shows the table, and as you can see, after 22, there is a strange div there, suposed to be 23 like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7hpu.jpg) image where the limit is 23.

I would also like change the left numbers (06,07,08,...) to hours (07:00,08:00,...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/maxTime/ says

> "Determines the end time **(exclusively)** that will be displayed".

(my bold)

This means that if you set `maxTime: 23:00` then the last time displayable will be `22:59`. What you are seeing is the correct and documented behaviour of the calendar.

Comment: Well, better put limit to 24 so it doens't appear